# Where to find someone to work on quant trading strategies together?

Tags: quant-trading-strategies

I work on designing quant and mix of quant+fundamental trading strategies, but find it is really unproductive to do it at home by myself, and looking to find someone who to do it together with.

I've built my own backtester, invested quite a lot of time on it, but don't really know where to find someone socially.

Any suggestions of where to look?

Comment: Get a job in the field?..

Comment: Share some of your insights on social media, eg, twitter, reddit/algotrading, etc. Post something interesting enough so that people would come to you.

Comment: There are some organizations like iaqf.org qafafew.org cfainstitute.org and others that bring people together for lectures and discussion of quant finance. Might be a way to meet like minded ppl. But best way might be to get a job in a firm that already has some viable quant strategies.

Comment: I'd second autoencoder's comment - I personally write a blog on trading system development and, through its contact me section, people have approached me with ideas/suggestions etc. for collaboration on work.

Comment: @Hasek not really a realistic option unfortunately (although I'd love to do that in a perfect world) - I work in finance, but in a different area - in private equity - and idea behind the whole thing is to keep doing it and apply fundamental analysis ideas to build strategies

Comment: @autoencoder thank you! will give that a go

Comment: @babelproofreader - thank you! will try doing that. I already have a website around my approach (anagami.ai) but haven't gotten around to posting something on social media in detail. I tried doing a few newsletters based on the analysis on my twitter account @ gulag_cp - but haven't really spent much time on creating something popular